# Can't get textarea value from custom dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#forcedcancel").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#forceDialog").remove();

    var forcedialog = "";
    forcedialog += '<div id="forceDialog">';
    forcedialog += '<h3>Reason for force cancelling the lesson</h3>';
    forcedialog += '<p><textarea id="forcereason">A causa di </textarea><p>';
    forcedialog += '<button id="submitforce" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button><button id="cancelforce" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>';
    forcedialog += '<input type="hidden" id="dbv" value="'+bd+'">';
    forcedialog += '</div>';

    $('body').prepend(forcedialog);
});

$("body").on("click", "#submitforce", function(){

    var data = {
        bdv : $("#dbv").val(),
        reason : $("#forcereason").text()
    }
    alert(data.reason);
});
```

div with id="forceDialog" is showing just fine. But when I am clicking Submit, I can't get the value from textarea with id="forcereason";
I tried to change the code to

```
$("body").on("click", "#submitforce", function(){

    var data = {
        bdv : $("#dbv").val(),
        reason : $("body").closest("#forceDialog").find("#forcereason").text()
    }
    alert(data.reason);
});
```

But the only alert I am getting get is "A causa di ". The initial text inside the textbox. :(

Answer (score 2):

First of all You need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` to get the value.

I think you can u use directly  `$("#forcereason").val()`.Because id is unique